# Prove that $\frac{(mn)!}{(n!)^{m+1}}$ is an integer.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, divisibility, binomial-theorem

Well I could prove $\frac{(mn)!}{(n!)^{m}{m!}}$ to be an integer by considering there to be m×n different balls and grouping them into **m** groups consisting of **n** balls each.
But I could not solve this problem using the same logic.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't true. Consider $n=3, m=2$. Then
$$
\frac{6!}{3!^3}=\frac{10}3
$$
is not an integer.

Comment: Yes thank you I had misread the problem